# How to get XML content with matching tags in Pull Parser for Android?

Tags: android, xml-parsing, rss, imageview, xmlpullparser

I am trying to use the Pull Parser in Android to get values of image2 and image3.

```
<item>
<title>Title Goes Here!</title>
<picture><![CDATA[http://blahblah.image.jpg]]></picture>
<picture><![CDATA[http://blahblah.image2.jpg]]></picture>
<picture><![CDATA[http://blahblah.image3.jpg]]></picture>
</item>


...
case XmlPullParser.END_TAG
if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("item")
_feed.addItem(_item);
} else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("title")) {
_item.setTitle(theString)
} else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("picture")) {
_item.setLargeImage(theString)
} else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("picture")) {
_item.setLargeImage2(theString)
} else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("picture")) {
_item.setLargeImage3(theString)
}
break;
...
```

I can parse and load the first image but, I don't know what the next step is to get the other images? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Doesn't it seem to make more sense to store the image url's in a list, as opposed to separate variables? Anyways, for your current code you should have only one `tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("picture")` condition (anything after the first `if` will never be run anyhow) and keep a running count of how many urls you've processed, which you can then use to invoke the appropriate setter.

Comment: +1 on the List. Keep a list variable and append the URLs you run with the "picture" tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a logic error in your code:

```
} else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("picture")) {
    _item.setLargeImage(theString)
} else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("picture")) {
    _item.setLargeImage2(theString)
} else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("picture")) {
    _item.setLargeImage3(theString)
}
```

The code that follows the second and third `else if` condition test will never be executed, if the encountered tag is `picture`, the control flow will end at the first `if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("picture"))`.

You may do the following to achieve what you want:

```
List<String> imageList = new ArrayList<String>();
} else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("picture")) {
    imageList.add(theString);
}

// after you finish parsing the xml file, set the image URLs on your item.
_item.setLargeImage(imageList.get(0));
_item.setLargeImage2(imageList.get(1));
_item.setLargeImage3(imageList.get(2));
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I know it is  correct. I am just have a trouble implementing it.